# What is an electrical relay on a bus (vehicle) made of?

Tags: relay, electrical

I was driving a bus and had the heaters and defroster on high.  But this turned out to be too much amperage for this old bus -- an electrical relay caught fire and smoke was billowing into the bus.  Does anyone know what the relay is made of? Because I'm still recovering from the effects of this smoke inhalation.

Comment: The smoke undoubtedly came from the plastic parts of the relay, which could be pretty much anything. You'd have to contact the manufacturer.

Comment: Most plastic and even IC epoxy melting fumes are toxic for sustained intake

Answer (score 0):

Relay contacts are made from a silver alloy and thus oxidize with age but wiped clean from arc when switching. Erosion causes ESR to rise and must be maintained by inspection or measure voltage drop under load and replaced if more than a couple watt loss on small contact surface Vdrop*I=Pd watts

Use fuse ratings and replace with greater capacity relay. If wiring melted ensure corrosion free connections checked by maintenance.

The relay contacts are non toxic but the PVC wire insulation is toxic from chlorinated gas fumes. I would have stopped the bus immediately and turned down accessories or shutoff bus and call for replacement bus, but I’m guessing in excited states he may push for litigation on lack of maintenance. The relay may be sealed type which if burned could also be toxic plastic smoke , so hard to say where/what without more forensic details.

Comment: I think the OP was more concerned with the health effects of whatever was burning more than doing the actual repair.

Comment: Yes I know, but it was the wrong question